# Auto login and run skype for linux without Keyring prompt

Tags: skype, autostart, keyrings, auto-login

I use Ubuntu 16.04 I also use auto login.
I have set Skype for linux to auto start, but it asks for Keyring password.

Is it possible to start without this prompt?

I mean only for Skype, I don't want to set a blank password for my whole Keyring.